# Is there any benefit in crafting items you can't use? Gain experience, selling, etc?

Tags: diablo-iii

In other games you can craft to up experience but that doesn't seem to be the case in diablo so is there any reason to craft things that you're not going to equip?

What about selling, is it worth it to craft certain items just to sell them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this was a feature of the early beta that you leveled your Blacksmith by making things - however this was removed.

The only way to level the Blacksmith is with gold and later, Blacksmithing Pages.

Items will cost more to craft than to sell them back to the vendor. However, you may get lucky on the player-run auction house.

Answer (score 3):

The only benefit is if you're looking to upcycle your crafting components into gold. Even then, the efficacy of using the Blacksmith to do so is... dicey at best.

If we use current (and likely unsustainably low) prices for subtle essence, and look at crafting an item like the [Apprentice Coif](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/apprentice-coif), between the crafting fee and the materials cost, you're looking at a cost of ~500g to make. So you'd need to be able to sell the crafted item for more than ~600g to realize any sort of profit on the AH, after the cut there. While a 600g price tag on a 2-effect level 9 cap is quite reasonable compared to vendor prices, it's also a sufficiently niche item, and there's enough randomness, that you're very unlikely to get lucky on this front.

For the most part then, the answer is no. One exception, is if you can get your hands on any of the plans to produces some of the Legendary or Set items that the blacksmith produces. Crafting those *could* be profitable, depending on the rarity of the items in question.